# C++ Input to a vector<float> without ending it with a non-float

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on a project where I need to input floats and assign them to a vector, I'm doing so like this:

```
//Input to temporary float
while (cin >> input)
{
    //Assign temporary float to vector<float>
    a.math_grades.push_back(input);
}
```

This works, but to end the while loop I have to input a letter.  How can I input to a vector and be able to end that input by simply pressing enter?

Thanks in advance! :D

-- Connor

Comment: EOF (end of file) can be signaled with CTRL+D if you're at a terminal.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that!  But out of curiosity, is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to indicate the end of a list with a blank line so that you can then move on to inputting other data, the end-of-file indicator won't help you much.

In that case, you should use `std::getline` to read a line at a time, end the loop on error OR empty string.  Inside the loop you'll convert each non-empty string to a float.  `boost::lexical_cast` is a good choice for the latter operation, so is [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)

Comment: @Connor `getline` into a `std::string`, then use that to create a `std::istringstream`, then parse that. Online examples abound.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yeah, I was realized that Ben already answered that and quickly deleted my comment, thank you anyway for the clarification.